# Is there anything to generically invert a C++ Comparator type?

Tags: c++, templates, comparator, std

For example, if I passed in `std::less`, I would want it to create a new comparator with behavior equal to `std::greater`. For use in templates.

Something that would enable a syntax like `std::map<int, int, std::invert<std::less>>` (except if the thing I'm looking for exists, that's not what it's called). Does this exist?

Comment: Some would say that the inverse of "less" is "greater or equal", not "greater".

Comment: That's true, but ideally what I prefer is less->greater. Although I'd like to know if it exists in either form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `std::not_fn`, [which](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn):

> Creates a forwarding call wrapper that returns the negation of the callable object it holds.

However, in this case, it would result in a comparator with functionality of `std::greater_equal`, not `std::greater`. Furthermore, the type is not the same as `std::greater_equal`.

Example:

```
auto greater_eq = std::not_fn(std::less<>());
```

---

For getting equivalent of `std::greater`, you get that by flipping the arguments. I don't think there's a function for that in the standard library, but it's simple to write yourself:

```
auto flip = [](auto fun) {
    return [fun = std::move(fun)]
           (const auto& arg1, const auto& arg2)
    {
        return fun(arg2, arg1);
    };
};

auto greater = flip(std::less<>());
```

This could also be extended to support any number of arguments, flipping only the first two (making it analoguous to `flip` from Haskell), as well as to support perfect forwarding of arguments, but those features may complicate the neat example quite a bit and are not needed for comparators.